# Redirect visitors to different places after a certain view count

Tags: jquery, wordpress, redirect

I would like to be able to redirect brackets of viewers to different versions of my homepage, so for example:

1st 100 visitors go to homepage1
2nd 100 visitors go to homepage2
3rd 100 visitors go to homepage3

Alternatively, I would like to show embedded code, such as an iframe, in the same manner, say, only to the first 100, and another iframe to the second 100.

I am open to all types of suggestions, be it jQuery, or PHP since I'm using Wordpress.

If my question is off or unclear, please let me know and I will try to be more specific.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this code to count page hits without a plugin - you could put a header piece of php to redirect according to the `$count` number returned

http://smartwebworker.com/203-wordpress-show-number-of-page-views/

Then use this to redirect:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php